# How to distinguish if the user is on subscription trial period or not in google play?

Tags: android, api, google-play, google-play-services

I am implementing a server-side service that checks user's google play subscriptions status. I use the Android Pubisher API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) to check the subscription status. Though, I cannot understand how to distinguish if the user is on trial period or if he has already paid (i need it for analytics, to attribute revenue)?

How can this be done?

Comment: is it one time payment or subscription ?

Comment: @Ak9637 please read the question carefully

Comment: any solution to this? @DataGreed

Comment: @Jorge nope, I just compare the time.

Answer (score 3):

When you validate the subscription purchase from your server, you are going to get the subscription resource like that:

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "startTimeMillis": long,
  "expiryTimeMillis": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean,
  "priceCurrencyCode": string,
  "priceAmountMicros": long,
  "countryCode": string,
  "developerPayload": string,
  "paymentState": integer,
  "cancelReason": integer,
  "userCancellationTimeMillis": long
}
```

The `paymentState` value has 3 states for subscriptions:

- `0` - Payment pending
- `1` - Payment received
- `2` - Free trial

You can always call the Google Play API to check this state.
API Docs: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource

Comment: how to get this json when a user purchase

Comment: @Aravindjayan you need to POST the purchase data from your Android App to your backend and validate it against Google APIs. [Here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44873018/2301092) showing how you can get access to validation tokens via your backend using Google APIs